# Использование лямбда-функции в качестве колбэка к WinAPI-процедуре

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, lambda

Есть отдельный колбек для обхода дисплеев:

```
int __stdcall monEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData){
...
```

Есть функция захвата экрана, в которой объявляются `CURSORINFO CursorInfo;` и `RECT display;`, после чего вызывается `EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr, nullptr, monEnumProc, (LPARAM)&data);`. В качестве последнего параметра передаю структуру из CURSORINFO и RECT чтобы в колбеке выбрать тот монитор, в котором сейчас курсор (на случай когда в системе более одного монитора).

Можно ли не объявлять внешний колбек, а вписать вместо `monEnumProc` функцию в стиле JS, захватив объявленные ранее переменные без всяких дополнительных структур? Просто в плюсах лямбды не использовал никогда, поэтому спрашиваю сработает ли такое и, если да, как это правильно пишется?

[UPDATE]
В результате разбора комментариев и ответа родился такой код:

```
struct view{
        RECT region;
        CURSORINFO cursor;

        view(){
            region.bottom = region.left = region.right = region.top = 0;
            cursor.cbSize = sizeof(cursor);
            enumMonitors = [](HMONITOR hMonitor,HDC hdcMonitor,LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)-> WINBOOL{
                (void)hMonitor;
                (void)hdcMonitor;
                view *obj = (view *)dwData;
                if( PtInRect(lprcMonitor, obj->cursor.ptScreenPos)){
                    obj->region = *lprcMonitor;
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            };
        }
        void Update(){
            GetCursorInfo(&cursor);
            GetIconInfo(cursor.hCursor, &icon);
            DeleteObject(icon.hbmColor); // not need
            DeleteObject(icon.hbmMask); // not need
            EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr,nullptr,(MONITORENUMPROC)enumMonitors,(LPARAM)this);
        }
        unsigned int Width(){return region.right - region.left;}
        unsigned int Height(){return region.bottom - region.top;}
        unsigned int CursorX(){return cursor.ptScreenPos.x - icon.xHotspot - region.left;}
        unsigned int CursorY(){return cursor.ptScreenPos.y - icon.yHotspot - region.top;}

    private:
        ICONINFO icon;
        // Define inner procedure;
        WINBOOL (*enumMonitors)(HMONITOR hMonitor,HDC hdcMonitor,LPRECT lprcMonitor,LPARAM dwData);
    } display;
```

Компилится даже без Warning-ов и работает.
Вставка кода лямбды прямо в `EnumDisplayMonitors` не сработала из-за ошибки приведения типов. Вроде в MSVS этой проблемы нет, но вот MinGW ругается. Во всяком случае цель достигнута, удалось уйти от `static` членов/полей в объекте.

Comment: Можно, но только без захвата объявленных ранее переменных. Контекст необходимо передавать через lparam

Comment: @VTT, то есть всё равно нужно где-то вне функции создавать структуру и её передавать в `LPARAM`?

Comment: Да, иначе захваченные переменные потребуют передачу в функцию дополнительного неявного параметра и она станет несовместимой с функцией обратного вызова для обхода дисплеев

Comment: @VTT, Спасибо. но как это пишется правильно? `invalid cast from type 'Screen::Grab(byte *out)::<lambda(HMONITOR, HDC, LPRECT, LPARAM)>' to type 'MONITORENUMPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(HMONITOR__*, HDC__*, tagRECT*, long int)}`. Это MinGW проблема или кода?

Comment: Вообще должно работать. Вот в VS поддержка преобразования не захватывающих контекст лямбд в указатель на функцию с любым соглашением о вызовах реализована. А в mingw видимо нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> захватив объявленные ранее переменные

Нельзя.
Туда надо передавать указатель на функцию.
Можно использовать лямбда-выражение, которое ничего не захватывает, т.к. оно может быть преобразовано в указатель на функцию.

Comment: `EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr,nullptr,(MONITORENUMPROC)[](HMONITOR hMonitor,HDC hdcMonitor,LPRECT lprcMonitor,LPARAM dwData){/*code here*/},(LPARAM)&display);` - так не компилирует. Ругается на приведение типа `lambda` к `MONITORENUMPROC`. Как правильно?

Comment: А вы не могли бы привести реальный пример использования лямбды как колбэка WinAPI? Я вот так и не понял как можно привести лямбду к правильному типу и с правильным соглашением о вызове.

Comment: `EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr, nullptr, [](HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) -> BOOL {/*code here*/return TRUE; }, (LPARAM)display);`

Comment: @freim, я добавил в свой вопрос код. Взгляните... может поможет )